# How to add & condition for jmespath query with az command

Tags: json, azure-cli, jmespath

I want to filter out two types in the query expression

**Json file :**

```
[
   {
    "name": "name0",
    "tags": {
      "env": "dev"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions"
  },
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "tags": {
      "env": "dev"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "tags": {
      "env": "dev"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
  },
  {
    "name": "name4",
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks"
  }
]
```

**Expression**

```
az resource list  --resource-group MYRG --query '[? type != `"Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions"` && `"Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks"`]'
```

But result is including 2nd type in the result

```
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "tags": {
      "env": "dev"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "tags": {
      "env": "dev"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
  },
  {
    "name": "name4",
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks"
  }
]
```

I have tried other expression but no luck. Could someone tell me what exactly I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding another  `type !=` after &&:

```
az resource list  --resource-group MYRG --query '[? type != `"Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions"` && type != `"Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks"`]'
```

You can also filter using **slice** to exclude "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions" and "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks":

`az resource list  --resource-group MYRG --query [1:3].type`

You can refer to [How to query Azure resources using the Azure CLI](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-query-azure-resources-using-the-azure-cli/ba-p/360147) and [JMESPATH queries](https://www.azurecitadel.com/cli/jmespath/)